# Como darle animaciones a estos progress bar con scripts en vue con tailwind css?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Busco de mil maneras para darles animaciones a mis progress bar y no lo logro, desconozo muchisimo el tema de los componentes.

Aqui les dejo mis progress bar, si alguien me echa una mano!

```
<div class="w-full">

         <div class="shadow w-full bg-blue-lighter">
             <div class="bg-blue text-xs leading-none py-1 text-center text-white" style="width: 45%"></div>
         </div>

          <div class="shadow w-full bg-teal-lighter mt-2">
            <div class="bg-teal text-xs leading-none py-1 text-center text-white" style="width: 55%"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="shadow w-full bg-orange-lighter mt-2">
            <div class="bg-orange text-xs leading-none py-1 text-center text-white" style="width: 65%"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="shadow w-full bg-red-lighter mt-2">
            <div class="bg-red text-xs leading-none py-1 text-center text-white" style="width: 75%"></div>
          </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="w3-button w3-green w3-left" onclick="move()">Run</button>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```